Trying to click on an element that is clickable manually, but not with automated test in C#
I'm trying to automate tests for a mobile application in C# using Selenium with Appium. This application was made using Flutter and there is a section where I have to select the purchase date for an item (picture of the element with its class and attributes are shown below):
Purchase Date Element
I tried clicking on the element using this:
IWebElement calendrierBouton = Outil.Driver.FindElementsByClassName("android.view.View")[14];
calendrierBouton.Click(); 

However, the code above doesn't click on the element. I tried using IJavaScriptExecutor and this doesn't work either. The code for this is seen here:
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Outil.Driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", calendrierBouton);

When I test the mobile application manually, I'm able to click on this element, and it brings up a calendar to select the purchase date: Manually Clicking on the Purchase Date Element
I'm using the BrowserStack platform to run the test. I tried using the SendKeys() method to type the date within the purchase date element, but this doesn't work either. Any advice on how I can click on the purchase date element to open the calendar?

How do you know it's element[14]?

@JeffC I used DevTools and it showed that it's element[14].

Its a bad way to find the element, and in your screenshot it says it element[3]

@mosaad Is the best way to find an element with XPath? I ended up using the XPath of the element.

@EvangelineDrink XPATH is fine but using xpath to find the 14th element is not the best way,

You can try using different appium versions to see if there is any improvement:
https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/capabilities
You can also check the elements if they are searchable in Appium Inspector.

Thanks! How am I able to access Appium Inspector? When I use BrowserStack's App Live, I only have access to DevTools, but not Appium Inspector (there is no button to access it).
